# Ignite server seems try to connect some outter server with public IP out of my cluster?

Tags: ignite

I have on ignite server running on the server on Ali cloud ECS server(same as the Amazon AWS), when I checking the log, I found some warnning and it seems the server try to connect some other node with outter IP (the outter ip seems also a Ali cloud server)
But my server is configured with static IP discovery:

```
    <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">-->
                    <property name="addresses">
                        <list>
                            <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                            <value>172.24.113.216:47500..47509</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
```

And the warnning log like:

```
[01:21:09,355][WARNING][grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-1-#35][GridTcpRestProtocol] Closing NIO session because of unhandled exception [cls=class o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridNioException, msg=Failed to parse incoming packet (invalid packet start) [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=ByteBufferNioClientWorker [readBuf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=7 cap=8192], super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=1, bytesRcvd=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-1, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, hashCode=407415574, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-1-#35]]], writeBuf=null, readBuf=null, inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/172.24.113.216:11211, rmtAddr=/120.55.13.109:40648, createTime=1527787269297, closeTime=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd=7, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=7, sndSchedTime=1527787269297, lastSndTime=1527787269297, lastRcvTime=1527787269348, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=GridTcpRestParser [marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=o.a.i.i.IgniteKernal$5@306c3eeb], routerClient=false], directMode=false]], accepted=true]], b=73]]
[01:21:09,356][WARNING][grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-1-#35][GridTcpRestProtocol] Closed client session due to exception [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=ByteBufferNioClientWorker [readBuf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=7 cap=8192], super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=1, bytesRcvd=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-1, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, hashCode=407415574, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-1-#35]]], writeBuf=null, readBuf=null, inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/172.24.113.216:11211, rmtAddr=/120.55.13.109:40648, createTime=1527787269297, closeTime=1527787269348, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd=7, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=7, sndSchedTime=1527787269297, lastSndTime=1527787269297, lastRcvTime=1527787269348, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=GridTcpRestParser [marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=o.a.i.i.IgniteKernal$5@306c3eeb], routerClient=false], directMode=false]], accepted=true]], msg=Failed to parse incoming packet (invalid packet start) [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=ByteBufferNioClientWorker [readBuf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=7 cap=8192], super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=1, bytesRcvd=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-1, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, hashCode=407415574, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-1-#35]]], writeBuf=null, readBuf=null, inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/172.24.113.216:11211, rmtAddr=/120.55.13.109:40648, createTime=1527787269297, closeTime=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd=7, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=7, sndSchedTime=1527787269297, lastSndTime=1527787269297, lastRcvTime=1527787269348, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=GridTcpRestParser [marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=o.a.i.i.IgniteKernal$5@306c3eeb], routerClient=false], directMode=false]], accepted=true]], b=73]]
[01:21:31,096][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#23][IgniteKernal]
Metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)

[01:08:24,828][WARNING][grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-0-#34][GridTcpRestProtocol] Closing NIO session because of unhandled exception [cls=class o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridNioException, msg=Failed to parse incoming packet (invalid packet start) [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=ByteBufferNioClientWorker [readBuf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=7 cap=8192], super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=0, bytesRcvd=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-0, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, hashCode=1820163947, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-0-#34]]], writeBuf=null, readBuf=null, inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/172.24.113.216:11211, rmtAddr=/119.23.174.205:56168, createTime=1527786504794, closeTime=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd=7, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=7, sndSchedTime=1527786504794, lastSndTime=1527786504794, lastRcvTime=1527786504815, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=GridTcpRestParser [marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=o.a.i.i.IgniteKernal$5@306c3eeb], routerClient=false], directMode=false]], accepted=true]], b=73]]
[01:08:24,831][WARNING][grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-0-#34][GridTcpRestProtocol] Closed client session due to exception [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=ByteBufferNioClientWorker [readBuf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=7 cap=8192], super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=0, bytesRcvd=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-0, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, hashCode=1820163947, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-0-#34]]], writeBuf=null, readBuf=null, inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/172.24.113.216:11211, rmtAddr=/119.23.174.205:56168, createTime=1527786504794, closeTime=1527786504825, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd=7, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=7, sndSchedTime=1527786504794, lastSndTime=1527786504794, lastRcvTime=1527786504815, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=GridTcpRestParser [marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=o.a.i.i.IgniteKernal$5@306c3eeb], routerClient=false], directMode=false]], accepted=true]], msg=Failed to parse incoming packet (invalid packet start) [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=ByteBufferNioClientWorker [readBuf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=7 cap=8192], super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=0, bytesRcvd=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-0, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, hashCode=1820163947, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-0-#34]]], writeBuf=null, readBuf=null, inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/172.24.113.216:11211, rmtAddr=/119.23.174.205:56168, createTime=1527786504794, closeTime=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd=7, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=7, sndSchedTime=1527786504794, lastSndTime=1527786504794, lastRcvTime=1527786504815, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=GridTcpRestParser [marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=o.a.i.i.IgniteKernal$5@306c3eeb], routerClient=false], directMode=false]], accepted=true]], b=73]]
[01:08:31,046][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#23][IgniteKernal]
```

172.24.113.216 is my private subnet ip, but in the above log, the rmtAddr=/120.55.13.109:40648 and rmtAddr=/119.23.174.205:56168 is not the IP owned by myself, it's two public IP of the Ali ECS cloud(I don't know if these two node is in the save private net with me, because it's not owned by myself), so, why the 
warinng occurs, and what's the warning stand for, doesn't it mean my node try to connect other node even I configured with static discovery, and it seems i have the risk of losing my cache data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`172.24.113.216:11211` is a server side port used for Memcached [1] and Redis [2] protocol implementations. So it's other way around - something from `120.55.13.109` tries connect to one of your nodes.

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/memcached-support

[2] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/redis